# Enabling VPN for RDP *only*

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn, remote

I was wondering if it's possible to enable VPN for RDP only.

I'm running Windows 8, and am doing a remote job for a client.

However, I have all sorts of other things (downloads mostly) which I would like completed outside the clients VPN.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my Windows 7 system with the built-in VPN client I just go to VPN connection properties -> Networking tab -> Properties for IPv4 -> Advanced... -> IP Settings tab, and uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network".

[image]